# Not able to login in facebook/Meta account

Tags: facebook

I am not able to login in my fb account whenever I login it shows me

**We received your information**
"If we still find that your account didn't follow our Community Standards, it will remain disabled.
We're always looking out for the security of people on Facebook, so until then you can't use your account."

Do anyone has idea how to resolve this?
I have already mail to FB but they are taking too long to reply.

Sorry for asking this question here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be an actual programming question, and is therefor off-topic for this site.

Comment: @CBroe, thanks for comment. you can(authority) delete the question but before that tell me where I should ask question related to login in website.

Answer (score 0):

No, the same thing happened to me just now, April 19 at 5 pm, and I was just about to set up the account for the very first time and was fiddling with the security setup by setting up two-factor authorisation, and by switching off the friends list from public view, and had not yet started to upload any material (as less than 30 minutes had passed since the account was created). That move triggered some automatic algorithm... I was just suddenly thrown out with the message that the account wasn't following community standards and would be closed in 30 days. I didn't even have time to upload a photo of myself or post a single entry to the feed.